# Нужно ли столбцы сделать индексными?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, база-данных

[image: scheme]

Про индексы читал, мало что понял. Насколько понял, они нужны, чтобы ускорять запросы.
Записей много будет, поэтому задумываюсь о том, чтобы в таблице `dpk_add_table_for_all_entries` столбцы `entry_id` и `blog_id` были индексными.
Помогите понять, нужно ли оно и если нужно, то какого плана sql-запрос на создание таблицы.

У меня пока получается что-то вроде этого:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  entry_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  blog_id tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY entry_id (entry_id),
  KEY blog_id (blog_id),
) {$charset_collate};";

dbDelta($sql);
```

Дополнение №1:

- в таблицах `%wpforms_entries` индексный столбец `form_id` меня не интересует, он в логике моего плагина не участвует (я его рассматриваю просто как столбец)
- в рамках подсайта записи в таблице `...wpforms_entries` уникальны, уникальный индекс `entry_id`
- в рамках таблицы `dpk_add_table_for_all_entries` `entry_id` неуникален, т.к. в этой таблице могут храниться записи с одинаковым `entry_id` с разных подсайтов. Иными словами, могут быть 2 и более записи с одинаковыми `entry_id`, но `blog_id` у них будет разный. Основываясь на этих данных могу предположить, что стоит сделать составной уникальный индекс, состоящий из `entry_id` и `blog_id`

Comment: Если речь про ВП, то ты не должен ничего делать в базе руками. Особенно если ты ничего не знаешь про индексы.

Comment: @SeVlad Откуда вы это взяли, что не должен? Нужно туда руками залезть, тк делаю плагин, у которого будет своя таблица. Сегодня не знаю про индексы, через какое-то время узнаю, не вижу проблемы.

Comment: Я "взял" от знания ВП. А про индексы доступно написано в документации и легко гугллится. Твое незнание этого ярко тебя характеризует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексы надо создавать по тем столбцам, по которым будет производиться выборка. Если столбцы присутствуют в WHERE запросах, то индекс весьма уместен.

В вашем случае, похоже, плагин будет делать выборку как минимум по двум столбцам: `...WHERE entry_id = xxx and blog_id=yyy`. В этом случае не лишним будет создать составной (composite) индекс.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  entry_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  blog_id tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  INDEX " . $index_name . " (id, entry_id, blog_id) 
) {$charset_collate};";

dbDelta($sql);
```

В данном случае составной индекс создаётся по столбцам id, entry_id и blog_id. Это ускоряет запросы, в которых присутствуют в WHERE один, два или три указанных столбца.